# How to read multiple tables from a MySQL in R

Tags: mysql, r

I have multiple tables saved in a MySQL database. I want to retrieve them using the RMySQL-package in R. I want to read a table and save the results in a dataframe or list having the name of the table itself.

Until now, I have the following code that doesn't work:

```
for(i in c("busconfiguration", "gendata")) {
    query <- paste0("SELECT * from ", i, ";")
    i <- as.name(i)
    assign(i, dbSendQuery(nexusDb, query))
    dbClearResult(i)
    }
```

busconfiguration and gendata are two tables from the MySQL database.

Any help is appreciated.
Cheers
Renger

Comment: Can you execute individual queries (outside of the loop)? Have you tried `dbReadTable`?

Comment: What error message do you have when you send this query?

Comment: Thanks for the replies: dbReadTable does do the job with the exception of the tables with JSON columns in it. It will throw an error:

In .local(conn, statement, ...) :
  unrecognized MySQL field type 245 in column 6 imported as character

If I use the following code
for(i in c("busconfiguration", "anothertable")) {
    query <- paste0("SELECT * from ", i, ";")
    assign(i, dbSendQuery(nexusDb, query))
    dbClearResult(i)
}

I get the following error:

 unable to find an inherited method for function 'dbClearResult' for signature '"character"'.